# Spring Boot Actuator / Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, spring-boot-actuator

I'm working on Spring Boot application and i use Swagger for the documentation.

I have adding Spring Boot Actuator on my application, but now i want to add the new services creating by actuator (/health /metrics ..) on my swagger documentation.

I don't find how configure Actuator and Swagger.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can configure in Swagger which paths you want to be added to the documentation :

```
@Bean
public Docket appApi() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            ...
}
```

will display all available endpoints.

`.paths(PathSelectors.any("/mypath/**"))` will limit only to endpoints exposed in `mypath.`

Answer (score 9):

In order to display `spring-boot-actuator` endpoints in [springdoc-openapi](https://springdoc.org/#actuator-support), simply add the following property:

```
springdoc.show-actuator=true
```

Comment: In my case, it created a circular dependency preventing the bootstrap

Answer (score 2):

**Update: 26-04-2017, updated implementation. Credits to [Andy Brown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1763035/andy-brown) for the tip.**

Due to our coding convention, we don't have a specific prefix for our endpoints, so I was looking for a solution to exclude the actuator endpoints, rather than to include my own paths.

I've came up with the following config to only exclude the actuator endpoints.
This way, I don't have to update the config once I add new endpoints nor do I have to prefix my own endpoints to distinguish them from the actuator endpoints.

```java
/**
 * This enables swagger. See http://localhost:8080/v2/api-docs for the swagger.json output!
 * @param actuatorEndpointHandlerMapping this endpoint handler mapping contains all the endpoints provided by the
 * spring actuator. We will iterate over all the endpoints and exclude them from the swagger documentation.
 * @return the docket.
 */
@Autowired
@Bean
public Docket swaggerSpringMvcPlugin(final EndpointHandlerMapping actuatorEndpointHandlerMapping) {
    ApiSelectorBuilder builder = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
            .apiInfo(apiInfo())
            .securitySchemes(securitySchemes())
            .select();

    // Ignore the spring-boot-actuator endpoints:
    Set<MvcEndpoint> endpoints = actuatorEndpointHandlerMapping.getEndpoints();
    endpoints.forEach(endpoint -> {
        String path = endpoint.getPath();
        log.debug("excluded path for swagger {}", path);
        builder.paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex(path + ".*")));
    });

    return builder.build();
}
```

Comment: That's not a very reliable way to catch the actuator endpoints. For one, your regex catches prefixes and not path segments. Better though to inject an `EndpointHandlerMapping` bean and use `getEndpoints()` to find the actuator endpoints available in the current version.

Comment: You are absolute right @AndyBrown, thanks for the tip! I was not aware I could retrieve the endpoints this way. I have updated my solution accordingly. Now with the full method to show how to autowire it.

Answer (score 1):

```
ApiSelectorBuilder builder = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
  .useDefaultResponseMessages(false)
  .apiInfo(apiInfo())
  .securitySchemes(securitySchemes())
  .select()
  .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
  .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/actuator.*")))
  .build();
```

Hi, You can exclude path on regex and you can chain them.

Answer (score 0):

Move the actuator endpoints into a context path through your `application.properties` file.

```
management.context-path=/manage
```

Then you can exclude that path from swagger

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("/manage.*")))
            .build();
}
```

You might want to exclude the error controller too

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(Predicates.not(PathSelectors.regex("(/manage.*|/error)")))
            .build();
}
```

Comment: It seems to me this does the opposite of what the OP asks. The OP wants to know how to configure actuator endpoints to appear in swagger, not remove them from swagger. It looks like /health and /info do not include swagger metadata.

Comment: @axiopisty I think your right, my bad. I misinterpreted because in my experience they were showing up in swagger by default, and I needed to try and remove them. The above was the best way.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatives:

a) Exclude path with a **NOT in the Regex**?

```
@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(PathSelectors.regex("^((?!/error).)*")) // exclude Basic Error Controller
            .build();
}
```

b) or chain and **negate a Predicate**:

```
PathSelectors.any()
  .and(PathSelectors.regex("/error").negate())
  .and(PathSelectors.regex("/manage.*").negate());
```